# use native commands when emacs keystroke is not found

Tags: osx

Using Emacs for Mac OSX

When I used Emacs on Ubuntu, if I used a keystroke that my Emacs did not define, it would bubble up to the operating system and execute the OS native command.

On OSX, it'll simply say "command not defined" even though I want to execute the Mac command. For example, if I customize option-f to open Firefox, and I un-define it on Emacs, I still cannot use option-f as intended because Emacs will simply complain "meta - f" not defined.

How can I accomplish this?